# Generic fast Transpose of non-square matrix CUDA

Tags: matrix, cuda, transpose

The SDK provides an example and strategies for tackling a square matrix transpose but is there a good way of performing a transpose on a non square matrix? I have quite a naive implementation currently as follows which is probably terrible:

```
template<class S>
__global__ void transpose(S *Source, S *Destination, int SizeX, int SizeY) {
    int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    if (tid<SizeX*SizeY) {
        int X = tid % SizeX;
        int Y = tid / SizeX;

        //(x,y) => (y,x)

        int newId = (SizeY*X) + Y;
        Destination[newId] = Source[tid];
    }
}
```

Comment: Why "probably terrible" - have you benchmarked the kernel? What fraction of peak memory bandwidth does it acheive?

Comment: Probably terrible because I haven't previously tested it. Profiler reports 27GB/s Write throughput and 5.3GB/s read.

Comment: Probably best to read in blocks to shared memory, do the transpose and write the block. Your writes here are not coalesced at all.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a reliable way of deciding on a block size if you have non-square arbitrary sized rows/columns though?

Answer (score 1):

Here my idea was to transpose the square part of the matrix with only the necessary threads/blocks (each thread swaps two entries of the square sub matrix), then traverse and transpose the remaining entries.

```
__global__ void kernelTranspuesta(float *a, float *c, int m, int n) {
   int i = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x; 
   int j = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y*blockDim.y; 
   int smallest = M < N ? M : N;

   while( j < smallest ){
      i = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;
      while( i < j ){
         c[i*m+j] = a[j*n+i];
         c[j*m+i] = a[i*n+j];
         i+= blockDim.x*gridDim.x; 
      }
      if(i == j)
         c[j*m+i] = a[i*n+j];

     j+= blockDim.y*gridDim.y; 
   }  

   if( M > N ) {
      i = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + N;
      j = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y*blockDim.y; 

      while( i < M ){
         j = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y*blockDim.y; 
         while( j < N){
           c[j*m+i] = a[i*n+j];
           j+= blockDim.y*gridDim.y; 
         }
         i+= blockDim.x*gridDim.x; 
      } 
   }else{
      i = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;
      j = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + M; 

     while( i < M ){
         j = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + M; 
         while( j < N){
           c[j*m+i] = a[i*n+j];
           j+= blockDim.y*gridDim.y; 
         }
         i+= blockDim.x*gridDim.x; 
      } 
   }

}
```

The kernel call is

```
   dim3 hilos(16,16);   // hilos(blockDim.x, blockDim.y) 
   dim3 bloques(8,8); // bloques(gridDim.x, gridDim.y)

   kernelTranspuesta<<<bloques, hilos>>>(aD, cD, m, n);
```

I tested it on 512x256 and 256x512 matrices, let me know what you think.

Comment: Looks good, I'm usually on matrices of around 3000x2000. Would it not be faster to do the transpose in the shared memory space?